# Can't resize partition more than 44 MB

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Recently I completely removed Windows and installed Ubuntu. I used 3 partitions on Windows. But after installation they are combined together creating a single partition.

Now I like to split it into 3 partitions again. I tried gparted partition editor, but it doesn't let me to split a part larger than 44 MB. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: Your `/dev/sda2` is an  *extended partition* which you can think of as a folder for holding other partitions.  The partitions inside of the extended partition cannot be larger than the original partition.  `/dev/sda5` is using almost all of the space inside of `/dev/sda2`